llamaIndex, how to query on a list of specific doc_ids?
I'm using llamaindex with AzureCosmosDBMongoDBVectorSearch.
While inserting the documents I'm specifying the doc_id. This is working well, and I can see the same ids in the DB.
I'm trying later to run a retrieve query, in a list of doc_ids. But it doesn't seem to work properly.
I followed this example from the documentation
query_engine = index.as_query_engine(doc_ids=["1"]) response = query_engine.query("What is this about? use only the data provided here")
I feel that the doc_ids are simply ignored, and the search runs in all the DB content.
